# Communicating between (chat) server and client

Tags: network-programming

just to clarify certain questions.

Let's say I'm making a chat application. Most of the online tutorials are basic server-client programs that send the chat message directly as strings.

So what if there is someone that came online, or offline. How would the client notify the server of such changes? What I came up with is to use flags {online}User, {offline}user, {privatechat}blabla.

What if someone knew how your code and that would allow them to sabotage by keep sending {online}blabla.
This would work, but has some flaws that I could think of as well. What would be the correct or better way to do this?

Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Or another example, in games. To tell the unit to move right, does it send a string back to the server {unit}{move right}? Something along those lines.

---

I kinda got the logic on how to make the chat server. If I just prefix a "{chat}" to the textbox. As long as I read this command "{chat}" I'll just ignore whichever commands which comes along.

How about in an RTS (not that I'm gonna make one, just curious), you mean there's literally 50 over strings telling how units move, attack, take damage, actions etc? Will all these commands be done on one thread? or multi-threaded?

Answer (score 0):

Well you have to implement session-handling and send sessionToken with your order to move a unit in game. So server will be able to check whether pointed user have rights to order the pointed unit etc. Same things with chats.

In my chat, every client sends some PING message to server every two minutes. So if 5 minutes passed and no PING is received, server counts the user as [offline].

If you are afraid of cheating users who reverse engineer your client and can make serious troubles to the system with cheats, you have to do two things:

1. make server to check if given
   user order is valid
2. implement bot-detection. check if
   user makes some actions with some
   constant time interval or if user
   uses some limited amount of words in
   chat etc.

I hope this post at least gives you some point.

The example of server logic is following:

```
[WebMethod]
    string LoginUser(string login, string pwd)
        {
            if( dal.IsCorrectUser(login,pwd) )
            {
                string token = dal.MakeSession(login);
                return string;
            }

            return "-1";
        }

[WebMethod]
    bool UserOrder(string token, string order)
        {
            if( !dal.SessionExist(token) )
            {
                return false;
            }

            int userId = dal.GetUserBySession(token);
            if(! dal.ValidOrderForUser(userId,order) )
            {
                dal.RegisterWrongOrder(userid,order); // For cheaters-detecting purposes
                return false;
            }

            return dal.ExecuteUserOrder(userId, order);
        }
```

In fact you can send string or any serializable objects as an user-order.

```
[Serializable]
struct UserOrder
{
  int unitId;
  int Order;
}
```

All samples are for c#. Just to demonstrate logic.

Comment: Ignore all rights and stuff. So basically the idea is really something like what I've said, by using strings with commands? Any quick example on this? "make server to check if given user order is valid", you can use the online example I made.

Comment: The login example is like following. Say you are using an ASP.NET web service as a server-side: